# Swift - sort dictionary descending by key

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, key

I am trying to sort a dictionary by keys (descending), and here is the code I have:

```
var codes = [String:String]()

codes["2"] = "Bitten by turtle"
codes["6"] = "Burn due to water-skis on fire"
codes["12"] = "Walked into lamppost"
codes["24"] = "Bizarre personal appearance"
codes["100"] = "Fall in (into) bucket of water causing drowning and submersion"


let unsortedCodeKeys = Array(codes.keys)
print(unsortedCodeKeys)

let sortedCodeKeys = unsortedCodeKeys.sort(<)
```

However, when you print the sortedCodeKeys, it's still not descending order. How come? How can I sort the keys by descending value? (All the keys are integers).

Comment: Because your keys are Strings, not Ints.

Comment: First: You are sorting *strings*, not *numbers*: `"12" < "2"`. Second: `<` sorts in *increasing* order.

Comment: @EricD Oh my god, this is embarrassing. Obviously. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

As said by ayaio and Martin R, your keys must be Ints to be able to sort the dictionary as you wish. You should also make a small change to your sortedCodeKeys constant, like this:

```
    var codes = [Int:String]()

    codes[2] = "Bitten by turtle"
    codes[6] = "Burn due to water-skis on fire"
    codes[12] = "Walked into lamppost"
    codes[24] = "Bizarre personal appearance"
    codes[100] = "Fall in (into) bucket of water causing drowning and submersion"

    let sortedCodeKeys = codes.sorted(by: { $0.key > $1.key })
    print(sortedCodes)
```

// returns [(key: 100, value: "Fall in (into) bucket of water causing drowning and submersion"), (key: 24, value: "Bizarre personal appearance"), (key: 12, value: "Walked into lamppost"), (key: 6, value: "Burn due to water-skis on fire"), (key: 2, value: "Bitten by turtle")].

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 & 5**

Here your keys are strings, for string keys sorting:

dictionary.keys.sorted(by: {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending})

Example:

var dict : [String : Any] = ["10" : Any, "2" : Any, "20" : Any, "1" : Any]
dictionary.keys.sorted()

-> ["1" : Any, "10" : Any, "2" : Any, "20" : Any]

dictionary.keys.sorted(by: {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending})

-> ["1" : Any, "2" : Any, "10" : Any, "20" : Any]